# Check if online in Arrowchat Integration

Tags: javascript, php, chat

I am integrating Arrowchat with my website. I am able to check online status for one user only. When I check multiple user in a loop its shows the status on last user only. Pls check my code also...

```
<?php
$getUser=new UserManagement($mysqli);
$getUser->getActiveUser();
if($getUser->count_rows>0)
{
    $b=1;
    foreach($getUser->values as $value)
    {
    ?>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
        jqac.arrowchat.getUser('<?php echo $value->id;?>','userdetails');
        }

        function userdetails(data) {
            if (data.s == 'available') {
            document.getElementById("message-user<?php echo $b;?>").innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="jqac.arrowchat.chatWith(\'<?php echo $value->id;?>\');"><div class="chat-now green" ><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Chat now</div></a>';
            }
            else if (data.s == 'away') {
            document.getElementById("message-user<?php echo $b;?>").innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="jqac.arrowchat.chatWith(\'<?php echo $value->id;?>\');"><div class="chat-now yellow" ><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Chat now</div></a>';
            }
            else if (data.s == 'busy') {
            document.getElementById("message-user<?php echo $b;?>").innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="jqac.arrowchat.chatWith(\'<?php echo $value->id;?>\');"><div class="chat-now red" ><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Chat now</div></a>';
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("message-user<?php echo $b;?>").innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="jqac.arrowchat.chatWith(\'<?php echo $value->id;?>\');"><div class="chat-now grey" ><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Send Message</div></a>';
            }
        }
        </script>
        <div id="message-user<?php echo $b;?>"></div>
        <?php
        $b++;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are overwriting `window.onload` all the time, so only the last function you assigned to this will eventually execute. And you are creating the function `userdetails` over and over again, that will also rewrite all previous instances.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.